# How can I force my $modal window to create objects on the main scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a main page in which I open a modal window on a button click. The new modal window is assigned the same scope as the main controller. I mean I create it like so:

```
app.module.....{

$scope.modalInstance = null;
$scope.myNumber = null;
$scope.openModal = function(){
    modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'template/modal/Modal.html',
        size: size,
        windowClass: 'small-size-modal',
        scope: $scope
    });
};
```

All the data the modal window displays is taken from the scope of the controller and everything works fine. Now there is also a text box input to capture a number from the user. And I would like that this number is directly created on the controller scope itself so that I can access it from the controller like so.

```
$scope.submitNumberFromModal = function(){
$scope.doSomething($scope.myNumber);
};
```

My Modal html input element is like so:

```
<div class="modal-content">
<input type="text" class="input-box" size="10" ng-model="myNumber"/>
```

But I see that myNumber is being created on a separate scope which I do not know how to access. Any help is hightly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$modal.open` creates a new scope with `$scope` as parent. New scope prototypically inherits from parent, this means that any object from parent controller's scope (including `this` in the case of `controllerAs`) can be used to bind the value and use it in both parent and modal scopes.

So it would be

```
$scope.data = {};
```

in parent controller, and

```
<input type="text" class="input-box" size="10" ng-model="data.myNumber"/>
```

in modal.

> But I see that myNumber is being created on a separate scope which I
>   do not know how to access.

It can be accessed with [modal's own controller](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal), any sort of controller interaction (e.g. [events](http://plnkr.co/edit/VjMdPHbelCCQiPLoOPFL?p=preview)) can be used to make it talk to parent controller.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please elaborate how I should change my modal instantiation for it to know about the data?

Comment: No change required, except the code above. Model's scope prototypically inherits from parent controller's scope. They will share the same 'data' object.

Comment: unfortunately doesnt work so far. $scope is again some isolated scope on the modal's own controller. Should I set the controllerAs and bindToController attributes to something?

Comment: You shouldn't, unless you need them. Modal creates [inherited](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js#L625) scope, not isolated. Your question lacks [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it is hard to say what goes wrong in your case.

Comment: It works  for me as it should (in Firefox, because other browsers don't support the scripts from raw.githubusercontent.com). 'data.myNumber' will be updated, while 'name' won't.

Comment: yes it works in firefox. was testing in chrome. so how do you think i get my data back to 'name', basically the parent? you were mentioning using some kind of event based triggers to interact back to the parent. Would really appreciate if you could plunk a sample on that.

Comment: 'data.myNumber' is already in parent scope, you can bind it to template. But if you want to send to parent on 'ok', events are more appropriate, I've added the example for them.